# React Native Expo Razor Pay

Tags: react-native, native, razorpay

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {   var options = {
    description: 'Credits towards consultation',
     image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
     currency: 'INR',
     key: 'mykey',
     amount: 11800,
     name: 'foos'
  
      prefill: {

     email: 'void@razorpay.com',
       contact: '9191919191',
       name: 'Razorpay Softwares'
      },
      theme: {color: '#F37254'}   }   RazorpayCheckout.open(options).then((data) => {
     // handle success
      alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);   }).catch((error) => {
     // handle failure
     alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);   }); }}><Text>Pay now</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```

Hey I am integrating razorpay into my expo app, used eas cli and launched in dev mode. I am not getting the **UPI** option for payment but rest of the options are working (netbanking,cards,etc) in test mode. Any clue on how to get it to work.
Have followed all the steps in the docs as well. Building the app on android. Thanks!